# NULL value in :conditions =>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
 Contract.all(:conditions => ['voided == ?', 0]).size
 => 364
 Contract.all(:conditions => ['voided != ?', 0]).size
 => 8
 Contract.all.size
 => 441
```

the 3 numbers does not added up (364 + 8 != 441). What's the proper way write the `:conditions` to count the rows which the `voided` column value is NULL or equal to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Contract.all(:conditions => ["voided is ?", nil]).size

 Contract.all(:conditions => ["voided is not ?", nil]).size
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Contract.all(:conditions => {:voided => nil})
```

or

```
Contract.all(:conditions => ['voided IS NULL'])
```